# Regular Expression Space character not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

My Regex is for a canadian postal code and only allowing the valid letters:
`Regex pattern = new Regex("^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][/s][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$");`
The problem I am having is that I want to allow for a space to be put in between the each set but cannot find the correct character to use.

Comment: are you searching for \s ?

Comment: you mean this `^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9]\s[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]\s[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$`

Comment: The one back slash produces and error two doesn't work and one forward slash doesnt work either.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to implement this regex?

Comment: Like simplify the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a forward-slash instead of a backslash in your regular expression for whitespace (\s). The following regex should work.

```
@"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][\s][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$"
```

[image: Regexper]

Comment: the one slash is giving me an error (unrecognized escape character) So I've tried two [\\s] and it doesn't work either.

Comment: i've updated my answer above, but KcDoD is also correct below in that using @ will declare a string literal and allow you to avoid providing the escape sequence. Also, the image above represents a visual breakdown of the regex above to verify that is what you're looking for.

Comment: in addition, if you're looking for 0-1 vs 1 you can use \s? (0-1) vs \s (exactly 1) to limit the space usage. otherwise, everything should work out if you're using the literal since C# will not require the escapes.

Comment: Wonderful! I want to plug regexper.com and rubular.com for being awesome resources for testing your regular expressions in the future as well. I've used them a good bit to learn regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply searching for space use `\s`

To provide the escape sequence character `\` use `@` verbitm literal character as below in the given example.

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9]\s[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ[0-9]\s[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$");
```

As pointed out in the comments, if space is optional you can use `?` quantifier as below.

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9]\s?[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ[0-9]\s?[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$");
```

Comment: If he wants to "allow for," rather than "require," the space, I think he probably wants to add `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\s` token for whitespace instead of `/s`.

Some handy tools to speed up regex development:

- [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) helps with syntax and provides realtime testing
- [regexpr.com](http://regexper.com/) (yes I know :)) visualizes your expression.

Comment: the \s is throwing an unrecognized escape character

Answer (score 0):

As per other answers....

- Use `\s` instead of `/s`
- You shouldn't need to square bracket the `[\s]`, because it already implies a complete class of characters.

Also...

- In most languages, you probably don't want to use double quotes `"..."` as delimiters to the Regex, since this might be interpolating the `\s` before the pattern is applied. It's certainly worth a try.
- Use a trailing quantifier `\s*` or `\s?` to allow the space to be optional.